# How should I call the result after I run a code in ubuntu terminal?

Tags: command-line

I am trying to run a SageMath code on AWS through the Ubuntu terminal. I have successfully run the code. Now I want to see the computation results without abusing "print". The results are saved in several variables in my code. How should I call them after running the code?

The problem is that my output is large matrices. If I need to run other scripts and check the saved result frequently, it will be inefficient since I have to scroll up and down. So I wonder if there is a good way to call the result only when I need it.

My Ubuntu version is 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Whats wrong with priting them, if you want to show them on the console?

Comment: I guess you are right. But the problem is that my output is large matrices. If I need to run other scripts and check the saved result frequently, it will be inefficient since I have to scroll up and down. So I wonder if there is a good way to call the result only when I need it.

Comment: I do not know your software, but the common way would be to either print it, have the software you utilize write it to a file, or employ redirects (e.g. `./command > savedoutput`). I also added your clarification to the question, so I hope someone familiar with your software can give you a perfect answer :)

Comment: Perhaps relevant? [Hide the Output](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/7869/hide-the-output/)